# grab number from an array of string - regex - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have an array of strings; they are URLs.  I would like to grab a specific number from each URL.

These urls are in this format:

```
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-111111-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk"
```

I would like to grab the fifth digit code after `banner?l_id`, which is `111111`.  Keep in mind the fifth digit code and the other ones can be any random number, it's not always zeros or ones.

Array sample:

```
["http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-111111-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
 "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-111111-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
 "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-111111-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
 "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-111111-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
 "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-111111-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk"
 ]
```

Like I said, I have an array of url strings and trying to figure it out how to grab the fifth digit code using Javascript; regex could help me achieve this but I'm not familiar w/ regex.

I was told python could be easier to solve this, but I'm building a chrome ext. which is using JS.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889391/regex-get-numbers-after-certain-character-string

Comment: `/\/banner\?l_id=(?:\w+-){4}(\w+)/` and grab captured group #1

Comment: @anubhava this worked, thanks!  I'm still learning regex, and I recognized a few regex codes, but I'm not sure what it's doing after `l_id`.  You don't mind explaining what's behind this set of code?  Again, thanks so much for your help

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried to do the `split` using the `-` but I went back to the same dilemma, how to grab the fourth `-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it without Regex with just split() chained with apropriate index choice :

```js
var addresses = ["http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-111111-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
 "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-111111-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
 "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-111111-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
 "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-111111-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
 "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-111111-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk"
 ];
var results = addresses.map(x => x.split("?")[1].split("&")[0].split("-")[4])
console.log(results);
```

Comment: thanks so much for you help.  I have another question for this code.  How can i use this code to grab the urls w/ unique fifth code?  So in the address array, the content will be something like "...111..", "...111...", "...222...", "...222...", "....333...", "...333...".  At the end I would like to have urls with unique fifth code, "...111...", "...222...", "...333...".

Comment: you should post as a new question because it's hard to answer in a comment box. But solution would be filter((x, i, arr) => arr.lastIndexOf(x) === i)